# Banging/Snapping Sound When Turning ('04 TrailBlazer)

Tags: suspension

I'm thinking that this is the sway bar or sway bar links.  Does this sound right?  This happens often and it doesn't matter which way I turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, I'd suspect the strut bearing plates if it has struts in the front (I'm not familiar with that particular model)...  Those plates usually last about 5-10 years, then start falling apart.  Makes snapping/banging/sometimes even grinding noises when turning.  Eventually the steering will start to bind up and popping noises will start.

Answer (score 1):

First thing i'd get checked is your wheel balances on all 4 tires. It's usually the most common cause of vibrations at higher speeds from my experience.